# Unmask Password textbox not working

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have the following code to display a GUI with a textbox and checkbox:

```bsh
Add-Type -Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms'

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

$password = New-Object Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$password.PasswordChar = '*'
$form.Controls.Add($password)

$checkBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox2.add_click($handler_button1_Click)
$form.Controls.Add($checkBox2)

$handler_button1_Click = {
    if ($checkBox2.Checked) {      
        $password.PasswordChar = '\0' // [char]\0 tried this too
    } else {
        $password.PasswordChar = '*'
    }
}

$form.ShowDialog()
```

I am unmasking the characters when the checkbox was checked but I am getting the exception as

> Cannot convert value "\0" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long."

So can some one let me know how can I handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell the backslash is not an escape character, so `'\0'` is a string with a literal backslash followed by the character "0" (ASCII character 48). To get the ASCII character 0 cast the integer value 0 to a char.

```
$password.PasswordChar = [char]0
```

Just assigning an integer value 0 would work too:

```
$password.PasswordChar = 0
```

Comment: Thanks `Ansgar Wiechers`